# Oracler Query Tallying wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

[sqlpic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pTjo.png)i have an oracle query that i am using to pull some date then further sort in excel

```
SELECT
    e.event_code,
    e.event_date,
    e.description,
    es.price,
    section.section_code,
    [enter image description here][1]seat.row_,
    COUNT(es.ticket_id) AS attendance
FROM
    event e
    LEFT JOIN event_seat es ON e.event_id = es.event_id
    RIGHT JOIN section ON es.section_id = section.section_id
    RIGHT JOIN seat ON section.section_id = section_id
WHERE
    e.description LIKE '%Test%'
    AND e.description NOT LIKE '%Gif%'
    AND e.event_date BETWEEN '1-NOV-22%' AND '31-DEC-22%'
    AND e.event_status_code <> 'HLD'
    AND e.venue_id = 1081
GROUP BY
    e.event_code,
    e.event_date,
    e.description,
    es.price,
    section.section_code,
    seat.row_
ORDER BY
    e.event_code
```

it returns a super high number of like 170 for section a row 1 of 170 when there is ONLY possible 16   per row i dont quite know what it is counting... im still sort of new to oracle

Comment: It is not possible to answer your problem without seeing the data that you are working with. If you can provide some sample data (in text, not an image) and the result that you are trying to achieve with that sample data, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVER** store dates as strings (and if you must store them as strings <sup>(really, please don't)</sup> then store them in ISO-8166 `YYYY-MM-DD` format and not as `DD-MON-RR` format).

---

You have the filter:

```sql
e.event_date BETWEEN '1-NOV-22%' AND '31-DEC-22%'
```

For this not to raise an exception, `e.event_date` must be a string and then you are going to perform an alpha-numeric comparison between the values rather than comparing them as dates (because they are not dates, they are strings). This means if `e.event_date` is the string `22-JAN-01` then you compare the first characters and `2` is between `1` and `3` therefore `'22-JAN-01' BETWEEN '1-NOV-22%' AND '31-DEC-22%'` will be true; which is almost certainly not what you want or expect.

---

If you want to compare them as dates then compare them as dates:

```sql
TO_CHAR(e.event_date, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
   BETWEEN DATE '2022-11-01'
   AND     TIMESTAMP '2022-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: i appreciate the heads up ! didnt know that.... will that give me  different results for my numbers ?